# iPad special keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard

An autistic boy is using iPad for communication.
But he tend to repeat some of the keys.
repppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppeat instaed of repeat

Is it possible to solve this by a special sw?

Develop an app that will modify the keyboard?
Or install additional keyboard as additional language?
Or install a hook on the keyboard stream and filter it? (windows allows it)

I am not sure if Apple allows any of these ...

Any other solution?

Please note that I am not looking into developing a special application for him. I want him to be able to use any application.

Thanks
Ori

Comment: on iPad keyboards there is no repeat function, to type a letter 30 times requests to touch down an up the letter 30 individual times. the only execption is _backspace_.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find an answer I came across this.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imean/id364906155?mt=8

Hope this can help. In any case I will keep you posted on this if i find something more..